# Rotate texture at the middle of UV and without tiling distortion (MAX like)

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

I need texture center to be in the middle of UV coordinates and make this possible
(gif video https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuyuI.jpg)
working in blender (gif video https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVrbT.jpg)

this

[image]

to this

[image]

File scene with plane and texture packed
https://www.mediafire.com/file/e3vm7hn08ajo8ms/Tiling_example.blend/file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Object coordinate

Object* coordinate has `0` in the middle:
[image]
Notice how I apply a `50%` scale, because *Object* coordinate goes from -1 to 1, so it's twice as big as UV coordinate going from 0 to 1)

### Offset, then rotate

**This is the worst solution.** You can subtract `.5` from your UV along X and Y, to make the middle have `0`, and then add it back after rotating:
[image]
Notice how you could use simpler nodes instead of Mapping, like *Vector Math > Add*, but while we're at it...

### Just use "Vector Rotate" node

And precise where is the center - the point around which you rotate:
[image]

Comment: Comprehensive! +1 from me.. Not on a plane, OK, but sometimes you need the 'worst' solution, to manipulate a 2D mapped texture?

Comment: I meant *"The worst"* for this particular scenario, I have no hatred towards mapping nodes. :)

Comment: @APEC the `m` unit is misleading there, the plane size doesn't matter. The UV coordinate starts at `0` and goes to `1`. So `.5` is in the center. Of course I'm assuming default UV mapping of a plane - you could unwrap your plane like this: https://i.imgur.com/SAE3w69.png - if you set your texture to *Repeat*, you will see the wrapping in the middle (A1, A8, H1 and H8 will all touch the middle) and that middle will have coordinates x:0, y:0. Now you can just rotate using Mapping and not offsetting. That's not the way to go about it, just explaining where the `0.5` comes from.

Comment: Thank you! I understood it and deleted the comment, but thanks again for the explanation!